# Blazor does not refresh UI when parameter is passed with onclick function

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

In Blazor ServerSide Asp.net core 3.0 Preview 6 the UI does not refresh. 
I have altered the counter.razor as an example. 
If you click the buttons "Set counter to ..." the counter is not refreshed. When you click the "Click me" button (is without a parameter) the UI is refreshed and 1 is added to the counter previous clicked.

The buttons seems to work, but the UI is not refreshed.

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<br />

<p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@IncrementCount">Click me</button>
</p>

    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var a = i;
        <p><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@(() => test(a))">Set counter to @a</button></p>
    }

    @functions {
        int currentCount = 0;

        protected void IncrementCount()
        {
            currentCount++;
        }

        void test(int i)
        {
            currentCount = i;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions how to fix this is or is it a bug in Blazor?

Comment: `@onclick` vs `onclick`?

Comment: I'm not (yet :)) familiar with Blazor... is the difference of `@onclick`(*Click me*) and `onclick` (*Set counter*) on purpose?

Comment: Was not on purpose, but I read below it is the difference between preview 5 and 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  `@functions { }` syntax suggests this was started with Preview5, but in Preview6 (current) the syntax for eventhandlers [has changed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/):

> Specifying event handlers in Blazor now uses the new directive
>   attribute syntax instead of the normal HTML syntax. The syntax is
>   similar to the HTML syntax, but now with a leading `@` character. This
>   makes C# event handlers distinct from JS event handlers.
>
> ```
>   <button @onclick="@Clicked">Click me!</button>
> ```
>
> When specifying a delegate for C# event handler the `@` prefix is
>   currently still required on the attribute value, but we expect to
>   remove this requirement in a future update.

So you need `@onclick="@(() => test(a))`

Comment: This is working correctly. It worked also when I added StateHasChanged();